# SVG incorrectly rendered, but looks fine in Chrome & Inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape

Can anyone check what is wrong with this `svg`? This is the file from a [famous article](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/), rendered correctly in both Chrome and Inkscape:

[image: svg]

My MWE in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/jsdmpczgwkkw):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includesvg[width=\linewidth]{./flow-matic-4.svg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: incorrectly rendered]

Comment: I would guess that this is either a bug in the `svg` package or the SVG uses some features that are not supported by that package. Either way you should be find if you convert that SVG to an EPS using Inkscape and the use `\includegraphics` to include that into your TeX document.

Comment: Remember that LaTeX does not support SVG, the `svg` package attempts to use `inkscape` to convert the SVG into a format that LaTeX understands. So saying that Chrome and inkscape renders the file correctly is kinda irrelevant as it is the conversion that is important.

Comment: @Raven Ok I'll try that EPS, never heard of it. `svg` uses Inkscape under the hood, and the file is rendered correctly in Inkscape, that's why I thought it should be included nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `svg` package uses Inkscape to convert a given SVG file to PDF and inputs the resulting file afterwards. By default, the Inkscape export is invoked with flag `--export-latex` in order to process any text in the SVG file via LaTeX. As your intention is to leave text as it is and not to process it via LaTeX, you should pass `inkscapelatex=false` to `\includesvg`.

This should work:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includesvg[width=\linewidth,inkscapelatex=false]{./flow-matic-4.svg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mister you saved my a** today!

Comment: OMG thank you!!!! I was going crazy!